# Ударение в слове "догмат"

Tags: орфоэпия

Указывают, что правильное ударение в этом слове на О. Так почему же так распространено ударение на А?

Comment: А почему вас так удивляет? Это не первое и не последнее такое слово.

Comment: Я не хочу сказать, что меня это слово *особенно* удивляет, просто по поводу других на этом сайте есть обсуждения, например, про творог, а про догмат — ничего. Вот и подумал, может кто скажет по этому поводу что-то интересное. Самому просто надо определиться, как говорить, решить, перестать говорить на А или нет.

Comment: Артем, все зависит от ситуации. Строгая литературная норма, конечно, д***о***гмат. В непринужденной беседе можете ударение ставить и на втором слоге. Как вам удобно. Мне, например, удобнее ставить ударение на втором слоге, иногда даже так говорю не зависимо от себя.

Comment: Пастернак: "Что ж, мученики д*о*гмата, Вы тоже - жертвы века".

Answer (score 4):

ДОгмат; (разг.) догмАт, -а; м. [от греч. dógma (dogmátos)] 1. Основное положение в религиозном вероучении, принимаемое на веру и не подлежащее критике. 2. =Догма (1 зн.).

ДОГМА, [от греч. dógma - мнение, постановление, учение] 1. Положение, принимаемое за непреложную истину, неизменную при всех обстоятельствах.

Хотя академические словари не рекомендуют или даже  считают неправильной форму "догмАт", в разговорной речи этот вариант применяется.

С одной стороны, слово расширило свое значение (возможно, именно во втором значении ставится ударение на втором слоге), с другой - пытается принять более  удобную фонетическую форму с редукцией гласного в первом безударном слоге.

Также обратим внимание на то, что на слух слова "дОгма" и "догмАт" различаются в большей степени, что, возможно,  также способствует перемещению ударения.

Comment: _Sergey: академические словари не рекомендуют или даже считают неправильной форму "догмАт"_ === Это не так. Не все _академические_ словари так считают. Словарь, на который я сослался в своём ответе, ведь тоже _академический_. См. обложку: http://www.bookmg.ru/product/691915

Comment: Интересно. Сам перенос ударения меня не удивляет, любопытно такое резкое изменение нормы. Из словарей: Аванесов (1987г.) - не реком. догмАт,  Резниченко (2009) неправ. догмАт, но: Словарь трудностей сост. Юрьева (2009) - дается одна форма догмАт.

Answer (score 2):

> Ударение в слове “догмат”

В ***"Большом орфоэпическом словаре русского языка"*** *(Каленчук М. Л., Касаткин Л. Л., Касаткина Р. Ф.  "Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала ХХI века: норма и её варианты";  М.: АСТ-ПРЕСС КНИГА, 2012)*  вариант с ударением на первом слоге *(дОгмат)* снабжён пометой *"допуст. устарелое"*, **в качестве же основного приводится вариант с ударением на втором слоге**:

***догмАт.***

Comment: Слава, если нетрудно,  посмотрите, пожалуйста, какое ударение в слове "договор''.  Не удивлюсь, если напишут: догов***о***р (устар).

Comment: Просто невозможно, чтобы в течении года слово устарело.

Comment: При чем тут в "течение года"? Если словари издавать каждый месяц, то оно и в течение месяца может устареть, если так рассуждать. Процесс длителен, фиксация одномоментна.  А дОговор никто не еще не признал  нормативным, так что можете не удивляться.

Comment: Даже так!******

Comment: slava1947, и это правильно. Фактически д**о**гмат устарел уже лет двадцать как. Я как раз тогда с философами и философией  контактировал. Д**о**гмат уже не употреблялся. Да и в школе уже, помнится были догм**а**ты. Как прим**а**ты. Тут другой вопрос, насколько уместно вообще использование этого слова вне философского контекста - особенно в единственном числе? Ведь "догматы" - это синоним некоего учения, по преимуществу - идеалистического. А что такое "догмат" в единственном мало кто объяснит без гугла. Возможно поэтому и произошло смещение ударения в малопонятном слове.

Comment: *Даже так!* - да почти так. Тут еще надо учитывать, что словари тоже далеко не всегда друг с другом соглашаются.

Comment: Я знаю, что процесс длителен. Но словарь Зарвы и Каленчук одного и того же года, 2012. Зарва признает только ''д***о***гмат, а Каленчук  - наоборот. Если бы промежуток между ними был бы разным - не удивился бы.

Comment: А что в этом такого? И при чем тут "один год"? Ну не меняются нормы по команде. Зарва, видимо, просто более консервативен. Разница подходов, не более.

Answer (score 0):

Догм**а**т (разг). См. Толковый словарь Ефремовой, Токовый словарь Кузнецова.  Такое ударение распространено, наверное, потому, что многим так удобнее произносить.